# Error using a Python Function in C# with IronPython.Hosting

Tags: c#, python, function

I have this code that worked before but not anymore. I do not know why.

I am getting this error.

int.PythonShapeAdd(int x, int y)
A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

public static int PythonShapeAdd(int x, int y)
{

    ScriptEngine engine3 = Python.CreateEngine();
    ScriptSource source3 = engine3.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("C:\\C#Projects\\ExcelAddIn\\ExcelAddIn\\Shape.py");
    ScriptScope scope3 = engine3.CreateScope();
    source3.Execute(scope3);

    dynamic class_object3 = scope3.GetVariable("Shape");
    dynamic class_instance3 = engine3.Operations.CreateInstance(class_object3, x, y);
    int result2 = class_instance3.area();


    return result2;
}
```

Comment: You cannot put code within a namespace. Put it inside a class. The error is pretty clear.

Comment: I have put the function inside this class

Comment: public static class ExcelDnaFunctions
{
    [ExcelFunction(Description = "Hello and Name")]
    public static string SayHelloExcelDNA(string name)
    {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

Comment: I have put the function inside this class

Comment: I have put the function inside this class public static class ExcelDnaFunctions and this function works inside the same class public static string SayHelloExcelDNA(string name)
    {
        return "Hello " + name;
    } Only the function with Python does not work inside the same class